# Problem with filteredValue field in antd table library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have a problem with filteredValue in antd table
I'm trying to use search method in some row (I added everything that I saw here [this link from official website](https://codesandbox.io/s/k9tjtj?file=/demo.tsx)
But right now, I'm trying to add like a filteredValue
[there is image where you see this search button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJkAG.png)[here you see like it looks where you click on search button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeTov.png)

So the find works fine but where I restart the page - then the meaning is lost value, so I saving in localStorage then take it from there, but there is problem if I don't add filteredValue field in settings that I need put in column's table props and If I add filteredValue something like this
`filteredValue: tools[col['key']] ? [tools['id']] : null`
tools (it's state that I take from onChange in table)

[so what am I getting at anyway? I see this warning and I don't know how to fix it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5l9L.png)

somebody know how to fix it ?
this my antd version 5.3.0

I tried use the another field that called defaultFilterValue (I saw some information about this field)